# In server 2008 R2, if I run an app in administrator's mode, will child process still be in the same mode?

Tags: windows-server-2008, process

In server 2008 R2,  if I run an app in administrator's mode, will the child process still be in the same mode?

I raise this question because I suspect the child process from the app is not running in administrator's mode.

Comment: Without knowing what type of "app" you're running and the way it launches child processes, I don't think we're going to be able to help you further

Answer (score 7):

Yes, child processes inherit the access token of the parent process (from [UAC Process and Interactions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835561(WS.10).aspx) on TechNet):

> Each application that requires the administrator access token must prompt the administrator for consent. The one exception is the relationship that exists between parent and child processes. **Child processes inherit the user access token from the parent process.** Both the parent and child processes, however, must have the same integrity level.

---

*Somewhat related bonus info:*

The `runas` utility has two poorly documented switch called `/showtrustlevels` and `/trustlevel` that seemingly allows you to launch (from an elevated process) a new process with a standard user token rather than your admin token, without lowering the integrity level of the child process:

```
runas /trustlevel:0x20000 cmd.exe
```

You'll find that the Window title contains `(running as [username] with restricted privileges)`, and whoami will show a restricted privilege and group list, compared to the elevated prompt:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will execute with Administrator privileges.

**Simple test:**

You can test this by opening the app as an Administrator and opening notepad.exe from the app. Try saving a blank text file to C:\Windows. If it does **not** throw a permissions error, then you know the child process (Notepad) is running with elevated privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the child will be in admin mode.

This is why running cmd.exe as admin allows you to start other programs in admin mode.